# How do I connect both my dishwasher and washing machine waste pipe to the same sink?

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine, dishwasher

My current sink plumbing looks like this with a single waste inlet.
[image]

When I remove the current single waste inlet, the connector looks like this:
[image]

I bought one of these (the connector is 40mm):

[image]

Is it wierd this has a hole in it?
[image]

But my problem is both the dual waste inlet and the sink trap have a female connector so I can't connect them.

What part should I buy?

Thank you

Trap from different angle.
[image]

Comment: Your trap is too deep. Can you include a photo from a different angle, so we can see where the drain goes after the elbow above the trap? With this configuration, the trap will contain a massive amount of water as described in [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qFcQJ.jpg).  With this much water in the trap, the drain will tend to drain slowly, and will be prone to clogging.

Comment: Are you saying the left part of the trap is too high?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: The trap is actually assembled incorrectly, I'm assuming to make room for the wye. [This image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/j8lQF.jpg) shows where the parts *should* go.

Comment: @Tester101 Thank for you help. I added a new photo of the trap from a different angle, it has some crazy piping going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part you have is for connecting to the top of a *standpipe trap*. Not for adapting a existing single-spigot *P trap*. The hole at the top is for air admittance I think.

> **What part should I buy?**

I would buy a "Washing Machine Trap with Double Spigot"

[image]

Example: McAlpine WM11 £10 ish.

Since your waste connection is quite high this might mean adjusting the other plumbing.

Comment: So I have bought the wrong part?

Comment: @Dan, Yes. I'd take it back for a refund (I've done that many times).

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick why is one of them pointing upwards and the other one downwards? Should I have some kind of special consideration on the height of the appliances?

Comment: @zom-pro: They swivel through  360 degrees to any position that is convenient for the connection.